# Sort columns based the presence of a suffix in the column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like:

[image]

The above df is just a very small sample. Actually I have around 8K + columns , I want to sort my dataframe such that all the columns ending with "_t1" comes in the end.
[image]

I can definitely filter out a subset of the dataframe with code like:

```
data = data [data.columns[data .columns.str.endswith("_t1")]]
```

and then merging. Can there be any other simpler way of sorting a panda dataframe based on regex pattern of column names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use `np.lexsort` to sort columns then reorder by positional index; to separate columns that end with "_t1" to those that don't.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['abc', 'abc_t1', 'abcd', 'abcd_t1', 'xyz', 'xyz_t1'])
df

# Empty DataFrame
# Columns: [abc, abc_t1, abcd, abcd_t1, xyz, xyz_t1]
# Index: []
```

```
df.iloc[:, np.lexsort((df.columns.str.endswith('_t1'), ))]
# Alternatively,
df.iloc[:, np.argsort(df.columns.str.endswith('_t1'))]

# Empty DataFrame
# Columns: [abc, abcd, xyz, abc_t1, abcd_t1, xyz_t1]
# Index: []
```

If you need to handle more complicated regex suffixes then you can always extend the input to `.endswith` with an appropriate regex.

Answer (score 4):

You can create masks:

```
m = data.columns.str.endswith("_t1")
```

Or mask by regex:

```
m = data.columns.str.contains("_t1$")
```

Then join together:

```
cols = data.columns[~m].append(data.columns[m])
```

Or:

```
cols = data.columns[~m].tolist() + data.columns[m].tolist()
```

And change order of columns by subset:

```
df = data[cols]
```